# !UpTime Twitch command (TwitchBot C#)

Tags: c#, command, bots, twitch, uptime

I was wondering how I would add a command for 'UpTime' in my commands that will show how long the twitch channel has been live for.

This is my whole code: https://pastebin.com/ty8J3vYS

I'm not sure if I add it into my commands with things added to it with another case such as

```
case "uptime":
    irc.sendChatMessage("");
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twitch's own API for this. Using this URL:

https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/CHANNEL_ID

**CHANNEL_ID** is numeric, so you'll have to find out what yours is.

Will return json, and within it contains the key `created_at`, which tells you when a stream went live, and from there you can calculate how long the stream has been live for. (`curr_date` - `created_at`)

Although, you will need a `Client-ID` when sending the API request. You can read more about that here:

https://blog.twitch.tv/client-id-required-for-kraken-api-calls-afbb8e95f843

Here is the documentation on Twitch's API: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but I kinda forgot how to add API to C#, C# and I don't get along too well. Also would I add `(curr_date - created_at)` in my Uptime case?

Comment: is there anyway to being able to have the command to show me how long its been streaming for? As in "This stream has been live for 3 hours & 32minutes"? Or is it only possible to have it be like"Stream started at 7:30PM"?

Comment: You will have to make the request and do the calculations.

Comment: Is there an easy way to use this API to determine when someone else's stream started, even if it has recently ended? For example, when someone raids me, I want my bot to turn off follower-only chat when my channel is raided, but only if the raid is from a channel whose last broadcast was longer than 30 minutes to prevent using fake raids.